# "The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"...DNN

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, oledb, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to get a new DotNetNuke site up and running on our 64-bit server, and I'm encountering the following error message:

"The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

I know from experience that you run into this when you target a 64-bit assembly on a 64-bit machine (there is no 64 bit OLE-DB provider currently). In that case, I simply target the x86 in Visual Studio and everything works fine.

But in this case, the site uses dynamic compilation, so there's no simple place to specify that I need to target x86. Any thoughts?

TIA.

Comment: I know this is probably a dumb question, but is the correct version of MDAC installed on the server?

Comment: Yeah, not a dumb question. I've got a bunch of other sites running here, but they don't use dynamic compilation, and I don't think they use Jet either.

In any case, the DLL's are actually present on the box, and of the version consistent with 2003 SP2.

Comment: Why is it trying to use Jet/OLEDB at all? It should be going to SQL Server directly. What are you using for your connection string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could change your app pool that you're running that site under to run as a 32 bit application.  In the IIS7 manager, its under "Advanced Settings" of your app pool, and then set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to true.

You could also do this with [AppCmd](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) from a console with the following:

```
appcmd apppool set /apppool.name:MyNukeSite /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
```

In IIS6 - you could try something like this (2 lines here, run aspnet_regiis when finished changing the metabase value)...

```
cscript %SystemDrive%\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

See the following for more info:

- http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5d306956-b2a2-4708-9bb9-72a395d474bb.mspx?mfr=true
- http://blogs.msdn.com/irfanahm/archive/2008/12/15/how-to-use-a-32-bit-dll-in-asp-net-page-which-is-hosted-on-64-bit-iis.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895976

Comment: Sounds like we're definitely on the right track, but this is IIS 6.0. Is that something I can edit directly in the metabase?

Comment: +1 for SO helping solve my obscure problem once again. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

HI, Now the Microsoft has released the  2010 Office System Driver Beta: Data Connectivity Components which is supported both in 32 bit as well as 64 bit OS. So using this driver instead of the traditional Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver will give us a 64 bit application running on a 64 bit server (that is what we really need).

Though this is in beta, it worked fine for me.

You can download this driver from [2010 Office System Driver Beta: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en)

Thnks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to target your application to 32-bit in which case you are losing the advantages of using 64-bit system. As aaa has pointed out, you can use the latest [Access Database Engine 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en) to address this issue. Please refer to [my blog post](http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2011/02/solution-run-jet-database-engine-on-64.html) for complete solution.

Hope it helps.