# How can I import an Excel spreadsheet on a 64 bit OS using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, excel, import, 64-bit, jet

I wrote an ASP.NET page that imported data from an Excel spreadsheet without any problems.  Then I moved it to the server and found out that it didn't work on a 64 bit OS.  After some Googling I found that MS does not have nor will it ever have a Jet DB driver for 64 bit OS.  Does anyone have any suggestions for a way to easily import data using an ASP.NET page on a 64 bit OS?  The client just wants some simple way to bulk import data.  Ideally it would be an Excel spreadsheet or a CSV file.  Ideally it wouldn't be super complicated.  They want the non-technical business users to be able to fill out a spreadsheet (or something similar) and then go to a web page and upload it to the server.  If there is no way to do this with a spreadsheet on a 64 bit OS, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Corey

Comment: "nor will it ever have a Jet DB driver for 64-bit OS" -- not true. Office 2010 will have a 64-bit version, which means that the ACE (i.e., "Jet 5") for A2010 will have to have a 64-bit version. It's not "Jet" per se, but it's going to give you full access to all current and older versions of Jet (including at least back to Jet 2, so far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a CSV if that's a possibility.

That way, you wouldn't be tied to the Microsoft JET Drivers. You could read the file and parse it using simple file IO.

Comment: Duh, of course!  Sometimes you are so focused on solving something in a complex manner that you forget the simplest way.  I will definitely do this.  Thanks.

Comment: This method ended up being the easiest solution.  That way I could keep everything 64 bit.  I found a nice CSV reader that someone else had built at the following URL:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx.  It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app pool for that asp.net site in 32 bit mode - and then the jet drivers should work.

IIS7...

```
appcmd apppool set /apppool.name:MySitesAppPool /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
```

IIS6...

```
cscript %SystemDrive%\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201918/the-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/1201990#1201990) for more details.

Comment: Do the JET Drivers even get installed on 64-bit platforms?

Comment: Yes, but they are 32 bit libs - so you can't load them from the 64 bit process that your app runs under.

Comment: Are there any down sides to running the app pool in 32 bit mode?  Is it something that I can "undo" if need be?

Comment: yeah, you can flip back & forth - just change the "true" to "false" or "1" to "0" depending on your IIS version.  Only downside that I can see would be that your app pool would be limited to 4 gigs of ram.  Beyond that, everything should be about the same.

Comment: in addition to scott i would suggest you create one web service and put all the logic of importing spreadsheet in that web service and return dataset or complete your operation. So you just need to enable App pool for that web service and not for entire application

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will let you import Excel workbooks and SpreadsheetGear supports 64 bit .NET as well as 32 bit .NET.

You can see live samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

If its Office 2007, then use the open XML format...... the rest becomes very clear :)